# Cannot access to Swisscom DB Service anymore

Tags: swisscomdev

I cannot connect to the database anymore. When I try to open the tunnel via cf service-connector I get the following error

```
cf service-connector 13000 10.0.20.18:3306
Creating tunnel ...

FAILED
Unable to parse domain
```

Comment: Please post more info. What CF CLI and plugin version? What desktop operating system? What ISP?

Comment: cf version 6.22.2+a95e24c-2016-10-27
    OSX 10.9.5 (Darwin discovolante-2.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Mon Jan 11 18:17:34 PST 2016; root:xnu-2422.115.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64)



ISP is Cable Modem via GIB-Solutions AG (always worked so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to uninstall the cf Swisscom plugin and reinstall it. Works again